# Define a command for building and loading errors file

Tags: vim, go

I want to define a command that will first build the current `Go` source file and load errors.err file for further use of such commands as `:cnext` or `:clist`.

What I have:

I added the following line to my `.vimrc`:

```
command Gobuild !go build %:t | grep -v "^\#" | tee errors.err
```

But I have to do `:cfile` after `:Gobuild`, as it is not done automatically. How can I auto-load `errors.err` file? Tried to append `:cfile` to the command, it didn't help. Auto-removing of `errors.err` after it's loaded would be useful too.

I know there's a way to do something like this with `make`, but I don't like it.

**UPD:** a clumsy, termorary solution (before I dive into suggested solutions):

```
function GoBuild()
    silent !echo -e "make:\n\t@go build \${src} | grep -v '^\#' | tee" > %:t"_makefile"
    make -f %:t"_makefile" src="%:t"
    silent !rm %:t"_makefile"
endfunction

command Gobuild call GoBuild()
```

Here `@` prevents `make` from echoing commands, `grep` filters out `#command line arguments` line, and `tee` is not to bother `make` with error code from `grep` (`grep` returns error code it there's noting to filter out) — `tee` always returns 0, `OK` error code.

**UPD:** a better solution

```
autocmd FileType go set makeprg=go\ build\ %:t\ 2>&1\\\|grep\ -v\ '^\\#'\\\|tee
command Gorun !./%:r
```

Comment: What don't you like about `:make`?

Comment: @romainl How would it look like? For me, following worked:
`:make src="%:t"`
And the `makefile` is
`make:`
`<Tab>go build ${src}`
But that long :make command is not handy. And I don't want to create makefiles, as I usually build random files in random folders.

Comment: @o2genum You don’t need to create any makefiles, see `:h 'makeprg'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the whole build and report errors business revolves around two options: `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'` and a combination of `:make` and a bunch of quickfix-related commands like `:copen` or `:cnext`. Adding a couple of lines in your `~/.vimrc` should be all you need.

[This article](http://richiewu.is-programmer.com/posts/33267.html) as some sample code and [here is a full-fledged plugin](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/vim-compiler-go).

Comment: The last update (see my question) is how I've done in with `makeprg`. Works well, thanks.

Comment: That's what I wanted to get at when I asked what you didn't like about `:make`: your `:make`-based solution is clean and solid. What not to like about it?